# Linq query to combine cell results?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I have a data table with this sample data.

[image]

Requirment is to make this data table so it returns all rows but for duplicate rows (last two for example) requirement is to combine there different values with a comma and return by making it one record.

For Example:

Gold-Silver,Metllurgist   19     Nick Gordon      . . . . .

Please help me.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

As Profession field is the only changing field, and you want combined value for this field, Following is needed
1. `Grouping` based on `Profession`
2. `Select` the records
3. Use [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) for combining Profession

You also need to define a concrete type to represent `Row` (`ProfessionRecord` in code below)

```
 var results = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(x=> x.Field<string>("Profession"))
                   .Select (  grouping => 
                               new {
                                  Key=grouping.Key,
                                  CombinedProfession = grouping.Aggregate( (a,b)=> a + " " + b)
                                })
                    .Select (x=> new ProfessionRecord
                            {
                              Id = x.Key.Id,
                              Name = x.Key.Name,
                              Profesion = x.CombinedProfession,
                            });
```

VB.NET From the [tool](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
 Dim results = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Profession")).[Select](Function(grouping) New With { _
    .Key = grouping.Key, _
    .CombinedProfession = grouping.Aggregate(Function(a, b) a + " " + b) _
}).[Select](Function(x) New ProfessionRecord() With { _
    .Id = x.Key.Id, _
    .Name = x.Key.Name, _
    .Profesion = x.CombinedProfession _
})
```

(I am not sure how much it is optimized as VB.NET is not my first language)

You need to add reference of  [Data Row Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) for the method `Field<T>(string fieldname)`

Comment: Thanks @Tilak, rows are not duplicated as Profession column will have different values even for same rows. I want to make datatable as it returns all rows and for duplicte rows it combine them and for Profession column it may make them comma seprated, as I mentioned on query. Please guide

Comment: I am sorry to ask again but as I am doing in vb, can you please give code in vb ? I am trying to convert it using converter but it says error which I am not able to understand what. Please