# Combining database cells in column B for matching cells in column A in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a table (data retrieved from a SQL database) in the form of:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════╗
║ Model ║ Manufacturer ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╣
║ A     ║            1 ║
║----------------------║
║ A     ║            2 ║
║----------------------║
║ A     ║            3 ║
║----------------------║
║ B     ║            4 ║
║----------------------║
║ B     ║            5 ║
║----------------------║
║ C     ║            6 ║
║----------------------║
║ D     ║            7 ║
║----------------------║
║ D     ║            8 ║
║----------------------║
║ D     ║            9 ║
║----------------------║
║ D     ║           10 ║
╚═══════╩══════════════╝
```

Each row is it's own `<tr>` when I bind the data to a `<asp:datagrid>`. What I need, though, is:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════╗
║ Model ║ Manufacturer ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╣
║ A     ║            1 ║
║       ║            2 ║
║       ║            3 ║
║----------------------║
║ B     ║            4 ║
║       ║            5 ║
║----------------------║
║ C     ║            6 ║
║----------------------║
║ D     ║            7 ║
║       ║            8 ║
║       ║            9 ║
║       ║           10 ║
╚═══════╩══════════════╝
```

I have spent a lot of time searching and have tried a number of different things, most of it using LINQ. But my knowledge and understand of LINQ is very little. I think (but I could be completely wrong), the closest I've come is from this question/answer: [Linq query to combine cell results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271835/linq-query-to-combine-cell-results). My slightly modified version of that is:

```
Dim results = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Model")).[Select](Function(grouping) New With {
        .Key = grouping.Key,
        .CombinedModel = grouping.Aggregate(Function(a, b) a + " " + b)
    }).[Select](Function(x) New ModelRecord() With {
        .Manufacturer = x.Key.Manufacturer,
        .Model = x.CombinedModel
    })
```

But because of my lack of LINQ knowledge, I don't understand the "defining a concrete type to represent `Row`" (which creates a problem with `ModelRecord()` in my code).

I'm pretty much completely lost at this point. Am I over-complicating things? Going at it completely wrong? Any help here would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Will this solution: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/06/02/string-aggregate-in-linq/ work for you?

Comment: Yuriy, that's pretty much exactly what I want to do. I'm trying to use that code (modified for the column names in my datatable), but I'm getting an error: `Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of Public ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char`

Comment: Could you please post your modified code and indicate where the error happens?

Comment: `From oRow In table Group By Manufacturer = oRow.Field(Of String)("Manufacturer") Into Group Select Manufacturer, Model = _
        Group.Aggregate(Of StringBuilder)(New StringBuilder, Function(Current As StringBuilder, row As DataRow) _
        Current.AppendFormat(",{0}", row.Field(Of String)("Model"))).ToString.Substring(1)()`

The error is everything after the `Select Manufacturer, Model =` part (that is, Visual Studio underlines everything after that).

Comment: Why do you specify additioanl `()` after `ToString.Substring(1)`?

Comment: No idea. Visual Studio keeps putting that there. If I delete it and then click to a new row, VS adds it back in.

Comment: You have to assign result of the query to a variable e.g. `Dim aResult = From oRow In table...` this way it will not add the parenthesis. And then use the result to bind to the grid.

Comment: Yup. That was it (along we me realizing the VS was also adding in `End Function` in the middle of the code). Thanks! If you want to make post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/06/02/string-aggregate-in-linq/) that I mentioned in my comments to your question works. Thanks for giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a DataGrid or GridView, I believe this is better suited to a Repeater, where you have better control of the formatting of the data.  Then you could load the data into a Dictionary of Models with a List of Manufacturers (`Dictionary<Model, List<Manufacturer>>`).  After loading the object up, you determine how to display it in the Repeater.

Comment: Would each manufacturer/model pair be a record in the dictionary (the model being the value and manufacturer the key)?

Comment: It'd be the other way around.  Since you have multiple manufacturers that create a given model, the Key is the model, and each Key has a Value which is a List<Manufacturer> representing all the manufacturers that create that model.  Editing my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Well, I know nothing about Dictionaries and format Repeaters, but I'll see what I can learn. Thanks.

Comment: You could potentially do a nested GridView or DetailsView in the Parent GridView instead of doing the Repeater, if you're more comfortable with GridViews.

Comment: Na, I'm sure the Repeater will be the easy part. The more challenging thing for me will be figuring out how to populate the dictionary, since our actual table has 350 records with 35 distinct manufacturers.

Comment: I assume that for each `List<Manufacturer>`, I'll need to loop through the table and populate the `List` as the Model changes?